# E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10061: Read-only file system

Tags: android, android-intent, view, action, call

I am trying to open the dial page on a phone and show a tel number in this page with following codes:

```
Intent intent_call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("09128317777"));
            startActivity(intent_call);enter code here
```

but I get following error:

```
E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10061: Read-only file system
```

please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with adding tel: into my codes. here is the code that worked properly:

```
Intent intent_call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("tel:09128317777"));
          startActivity(intent_call);
```